# How can I change pylint tab width from 4 spaces to 2 spaces?

Tags: python-3.x, pylint, pylintrc

I have tried `pylint --indent-string="  "`, but I keep getting the help message. What am I supposed to do to configure pylint.

Answer (score 11):

According to the [docs](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/v2.17.2/user_guide/configuration/all-options.html#indent-string), `" "` means 4 spaces.

You need to use single quotes: `pylint --indent-string='  '`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work Bad indentation. Found 2 spaces, expected 4

Comment: You should also update this: `indent-after-paren=2`

Answer (score 1):

I realize you're probably not having this issue anymore but figure i'd suggest another solution that could be useful for others.

Within pylintrc, generated with `pylint --generate-rcfile` have a look at the line configuring `indent-string`:

```
# String used as indentation unit. This is usually "  " (4 spaces) or "\t" (1
# tab).
indent-string="    "
```

Here whatever number of spaces or tabs you put within the parenthesis will be considered the allowed indent style.

You can then run pylint using this file e.g.

```
pylint --rcfile .pylintrc <.py file to check>
```

I should note that the documentation for pylint use markdown which folds multiple whitespaces into one i.e. (the "    " into " ") and hence can be a bit confusing when looking at the docs as it would suggest " " defines a 4 space indent.